# I tried reversing a string in C without using <string.h> functions, it didn't work

Tags: c, string

I was trying to inverse a string in c which seemed fairly easy at first but I keep encountering some weird problem that I don't seem to understand where it comes from.

The string c3 keep showing more characters that it should

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char c1[10];
    char c3[10];
    int i,j,l;

    printf("donner la chaine a inverser\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(c1);

    for(i = 0; c1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    }

    l = i;
    j = 0;

    for(i = l-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d%d\n", i, j);

        c3[j] = c1[i];
        j++;
    }
    
    printf("%s", c3);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not really sure but c3 should only have the number of characters that c1 does but it shows that it contains more in `printf("%s", c3);`.

I am still new to strings in c so I probably missed something really obvious.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the C specification explicitly say that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You need a terminator on the copy - '\0'.

Comment: Also never ***ever*** use the `gets` function. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that is has even been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Add `c3[l] = '\0';` before the printf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. let's say your string is abcdef. in c3, you will put fedcba, where a in at index 5.

What will be at index 6 ? The answer is "no one knows". it's undefined. That's why you have garbage after your string.

In C, a string is a char array, "null terminated" ( NULL terminated means there is the character `'\0'` after the last character ( or simply a `0` ( not `'0'`) ).

The simple way of solving your problem is to initialize c3 to 0.

`char c3[10] = {0};`

This way, your array will be filled with NULL characters.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing  my confusion !                                                                          definetly something to keep in mind when working with strings

Comment: To avoid confusion, `NULL` is preferably used for the null pointer. `NUL` is the ASCII name for the null byte.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set a null terminator at offset `c3[i]`. `printf()` will keep reading from `c3` until it finds a null byte, since `c3` a local object that is not initialized, `printf` may read and output extra characters as you experience, and potentially read beyond the end of the array which has undefined behavior.

Note also that you should not use `gets()` as you cannot tell this obsolete C library function the size of the destination array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c1[80];
    char c3[80];
    int i, j, len;

    printf("donner la chaine a inverser:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    if (!fgets(c1, sizeof c1, stdin))
        return 1;

    for (len = 0; c1[len] != '\0' && c1[len] != '\n'; len++)
        continue;

    for (j = 0, i = len; i-- > 0; j++) {
        c3[j] = c1[i];
    }
    c3[j] = '\0';    // set the null terminator
  
    printf("%s\n", c3);

    return 0;
}
```